# What is an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, physics, quantum-mechanics

since we are studying schrodinger's equation , we met with the Hamiltonian operator , so I was wondering what's an operator , and particulary the Hamiltonian operator ?

Comment: Basically, it's a matrix. The Hamiltonian operator is a matrix whose eigenvalues constitute the energy spectrum of your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being a bit simplistic, the idea is like this:

A **function** is something which eats some number-like object (a real number, a vector, a matrix, etc) and spits out another number-like object (not necessarily the same type).

[image]

Analogously, an **operator** eats a *function* and spits out another function.  An elementary example of this is the differentiation operator $\frac{d}{dx}$.  Apply this operator to a function $f$ and you get its derivative $\frac{df}{dx}$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \frac{df(x)}{dx}$$

The **Hamilton operator**, $H$, is a linear operator associated with a given quantum system.  It acts on (eats) a wavefunction (let's specifically consider an eigenfunction $\psi$) and results in (spits out) the wavefunction times a scalar (the energy $E$).

$$H\psi = E\psi$$

The above equation is called the **time-independent Schrodinger equation**.  It really is just an eigenvalue equation like the type you saw in linear algebra.  Only now your vectors are complex-valued functions and your linear transformation is an operator.